# DIY printer + Arduino. Can I use the position sensor? Multithreading?

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to make a computer-controlled painter/drawer/CNC, something like [this](https://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-3axis-CNC-plotter-out-of-old-printers/), from an old junk printer that didn't work... I have got as far as a working motor shield that can move the sliding trolley back and forth by running the DC for a short amount of time, and running the stepper that would be "paper feed". But it is currently just some gears and roller.

1: Assuming I can attach the paper-feed gear to a platform to move it in both X and Y directions, is there still no way I can multithread Arduino code? Searching for this, I found results in some really old howtos/forums that say you cannot, but you can fake it by doing one thing then another. I would want a serial command to send the Arduino to say, "start 3mm right" and while doing so, run "3mm forward" for example for a diagonal line. I've only run this on commands that are run intermittently and can block while the command is running [like so](https://github.com/programmin1/HowToTrainYourRobot/blob/master/StepperShieldTest/StepperShieldTest.ino).

2: There is a clear "tape" with lines on it that goes through the sliding trolley and has a ribbon coming out of the sliding trolley that I assume is reference indicating that it is x mm away from the end, that lets the printer see how long to move. Would it be feasible to reverse-engineer this type of device to use in this custom application? Could this be done with an oscilloscope output connected to pins on the ribbon?

Comment: You should really study how Arduino-based 3d printer firmwares (most of which are open source) solve this problem.  The tape you are describing is an *incremental* encoder, so it will only give you position if you count all of the changes in moving from a start position determined by something else such as a limit switch.

Comment: You could also look into using Grbl, which is a CNC style controlling software.  That might be able to help you run your motors, as it would be working with generic g-code, rather than having to invent a language yourself.

Comment: I strongly support @computercarguy. Building the CNC itself if enough work. And you need to be able to read the files exported by 3D design software. Better use an available software.

Answer (score 0):

You can multi*task* on arduino by doing stuff for one task for a bit and then do stuff for another task for a bit and switch back and forth like that.

However many arduino libs tend to rely on blocking calls and don't support giving control back to calling code so time spent in `delay()` calls can be used by other code.

Comment: Can it do IO threading? Or, with the way `Serial.read()` works blocking, would it be best to send a command like 'Left3 Forward4' and then run those at the same time with start motor1, start motor2, end motor2, end motor 1?

Comment: servo motor control is done using timed pin manipulation, serial communication auto fills a buffer that Serial.read() pulls out of. All of that can be done without ever blocking.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [AccelStepper library](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/) (installable via the Library Manager) which will allow you to drive multiple stepper motors at once without blocking commands.

1. It's possible to multithread on an Arduino but it's a sophisticated operation that you don't actually need to do for this application. Better instead to call one motor move, then the next, in rapid succession in your main loop. The AccelStepper library sort of builds this in when you're using it for position-based control; you tell one motor where to move and then run `motor.run()` as often as possible in the loop to actually send the commands to your driver to move it. (You *also* tell the other other motor to move, and also run `motortwo.run()` just as often as `motor.run()` in the loop; neither command takes much time at all to run.) For precisely coordinated multi-motor moves, look at the `MultiStepper` example included in the library, but note that the sort of thing I'm describing, implemented in the similarly-named `MultipleSteppers` example, will do the trick for you.
2. Regarding that "clear tape," my suspicion is if you look close, you'll find it's got lots of very narrowly spaced black and clear bands. It is used to report position data back to the motor driver. It more than likely has a photointerruptor that reads its movement. You can read the speed (but not absolute position) of that tape by monitoring the clear and black sections moving through the photointerruptor. For higher precision of data, likely necessary because the tape will be moving relatively fast, you'll likely want to use an [interrupt](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/) feature of the chip to watch the ticks as they go by, which is designed to take precedence over other would-be simultaneous operations the chip is doing.

Good luck with the project!